# maven-jar-plugin vs maven-jar dependency

Tags: maven

I am trying to run standalone java application with maven and to add maven-jar-plugin.
here is my pom.xml

```xml
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <type>maven-plugin</type>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

how could this plugin be added as dependency and plugin? how can I use this as dependency?

thanks

Comment: This question was asked here so many times before :) E.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11881663/what-is-the-difference-in-maven-between-dependency-and-plugin-tags-in-pom-xml or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15917352/is-there-difference-between-dependencies-and-dependencies-in-plugin-tags

Comment: My questions is more on how to use in case of choosing one of them with eclipse

Answer (score 0):

Well, a `<dependency>`in `<dependencyManagement>` section allows you to specify plugins versions in one place and then inherit it across several (children) modules simply by name, w/o further version specification, thus simplifying updating a plugin. A dependency is, roughly, a jar in your *application* classpath.

A `<plugin>` in `<build><pluginManagement>` allows to create a configuration of the plugin shared across several (children) modules. The plugin is used by maven itself to perform its tasks, so it's, frankly speaking, a jar in *maven* classpath. There could be also also `<reporting>` section for maven reporting, etc.

A `<plugin>` entry in `<build>` turns on this plugin for a particular module. Usually it's specified w/o version since its inherited. Also plugin configuration inherited from the parent (or from `<pluginManagement>` section within this `pom.xml`) can be overridden here.