# Does maven execute chained commands

Tags: java, maven

i am new to maven and I am wondering is this even possible in maven?

```
mvn clean install deploy
```

or

```
mvn clean compile install deploy
```

will maven do all the steps? thanks in advance

Comment: have you attempted to check the maven site, for example http://maven.apache.org/run.html?

Comment: Let's read this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/32759400/6743203

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are Maven goals and phases and what is their difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16205778/what-are-maven-goals-and-phases-and-what-is-their-difference)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is yes.

Maven has the concept of a [build life cycle](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html). In the example you have given

```
mvn clean compile install deploy
```

The highest phase is deploy which includes compile and install so it's the same as mvn clean deploy.

Comment: Or better to use only `mvn clean deploy` cause otherwise many parts like compile etc. will be done three times in this case...