# Maven - Why mvn install launches compile or test phase?

Tags: maven

I have been using maven this last few days.
I was wondering why the install phase launches compile or test phase too ?

I have read the documentation of maven, and as far as I understand, mvn install launches install:install goal.
It seems to me that before launching this goal, it launches other goals (or phases) which compiles and tests the project.

Does this mean that maven launches all the phases "before" install phase in the default lifecycle ?

Thanks for your answer (there is something I don't undertand).

Comment: You may be confusing "deployment" with "install"  Install means it will build the target and install to your repository.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are Maven goals and phases and what is their difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16205778/what-are-maven-goals-and-phases-and-what-is-their-difference)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

Calling a *phase* like `install` runs the lifecycle from the beginning up to the phase you call.

If you do not want this behaviour, you need to call a goal (like `install:install`) explictly (`mvn install:install`). Usually, building with `mvn clean install` is the way to go.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!