# Difference Between "mvn package" and "mvn compile war:war"

Tags: spring-boot, maven

What's the difference between `mvn package` and `mvn compile war:war`?

When I run both of these commands, they both seem to do the same thing.

NB: I'm developing a spring boot app

***Thank you in advance***

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are Maven goals and phases and what is their difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16205778/what-are-maven-goals-and-phases-and-what-is-their-difference)

Comment: Thank you but It doesn't answer my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second command does the most essential things (but no tests, no resources ...).

Always use the lifecycle, call `mvn clean package`