# How do I execute only the process-sources phase without building the whole maven project?

Tags: java, maven, maven-dependency-plugin

So according this this: https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.9.4/maven-core/lifecycles.html

I should be able to run something like: `mvn process-sources`

But it fails, for being unable to resolve an artifact from a module in this project...

And when I run: `mvn clean compile` OR `mvn clean package`, etc, they all work.

Am I missing something with Maven?

How do I **execute only the process-sources phase** without building the whole maven project?

Edit/Addition:

Here is the error output: `Failed to execute goal on project alarmsandevents-configuration: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.unnamedcorp.alarmsandevents:alarmsandevents-configuration:jar:23.02.01.1-SNAPSHOT: com.unnamedcorp.alarmsandevents:alarmsandevents-common:jar:23.02.01.1-SNAPSHOT was not found in https://artifactory-na.unnamedcorp.com:443/artifactory/embeddedservices-maven-stable-virtual during a previous attempt.`

What I don't understand is why it's looking for an artifact that hasn't been built yet when I run `mvn process-sources` but when I run `mvn compile` it doesn't, even though that is a later phase. I thought maven runs all preceeding phases when running one, which should yield the same error.

Comment: If using `compile` or `package` works fine.. What is exactly the issue to only run the life cycle phase `process-sources`? Can you give a real example, show the configuration? Maven version etc.

Comment: Have you read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16205778/what-are-maven-goals-and-phases-and-what-is-their-difference?

Comment: @khmarbaise I can't put much code up due to it being proprietary... I'll add the error output to the question, with some redactions though.

Comment: @Kayaman yes, I saw that, and it states what I thought would be the case, where if goal Z is executed then Goals X and Y (preceding) would be included.

Comment: So you read it, but you did not understand it "If you specify a phase then Maven will run all phases up to the phase you specified in order (e.g. if you specify package it will first run through the compile phase and then the test phase and finally the package phase) and for each phase it will run all goals attached to that phase."

Comment: "If you specify a goal when you execute Maven then it will run that goal and only that goal.".

Comment: No I get it, and that's exactly what I'm trying to do, run only the phases up-to-and-including 'process-sources' by running `mvn process-sources`

Are you saying that this should or should not work?

Comment: I quote you "How do I execute only the process-sources phase", so is it only or up to? What are you expecting to run in the process-sources phase anyway?

Comment: Your point? This is getting aggressive dude - should `mvn process-sources` work or not when `mvn compile` does?

Comment: That error message `was not found in https://artifactory-na.unnamedcorp.com:443/artifactor` shows simply that artifacts are not there... and based on that it is SNAPSHOT version which might be cleaned up after a time... without more information it's hard to even make an educated gues...Also the question would be is this a single module build or a multi module setup?