# Difference between 'plugin' section and 'dependency' section in pom. Which one to use when?

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

While searching for maven-check-style plugin information online I found that it can be added both as a `<dependency>` tag like this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
</dependency>
```

and also under `<plugins>` tag like this:

```
<reporting>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <configLocation>config/sun_checks.xml</configLocation>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
</reporting>
```

I would like to know the difference between each and which one to use when. Please guide.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11881663/what-is-the-difference-in-maven-between-dependency-and-plugin-tags-in-pom-xml)?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, plugins are also artifacts, so they can be added as a dependency to a project. However adding plugin artifact as a dependency, doesnt bind its execution to any phase of maven build, therefore it cannot be executed.

Comment: Never use a plugin as a dependency cause your project contains that plugin as dependency which is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find some answers:

https://www.quora.com/In-Maven-what-is-the-difference-between-dependency-and-plugins

"A plugin is an extension to Maven, something used to produce your artifact (maven-jar-plugin for an example, is used to, you guess it, make a jar out of your compiled classes and resources).

A dependency is a library that is needed by the application you are building, at compile and/or test and/or runtime time."Olivier Demeijer