# Maven Compilation Error: package javafx does not exist (with javafx-maven-plugin)

Tags: java, maven, javafx

I am doing a class project, requiring using Maven as build tool for a JavaFx project.

This is my pom.xml setting, where I use 2 plugins. Per my understanding: `maven-compiler-plugin` is to enforce java jdk 1.8 as compiler, and `javafx-maven-plugin` to auto download javafx library.

Also, my main launcher Main.java file is located at `src/main/java/Main/Main.java`. `pom.xml` is at the same level as `src` folder.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
              <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
              <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>3.5.1</version>
              <configuration>
                  <fork>true</fork>
                  <compilerVersion>1.8</compilerVersion>
                  <verbose>true</verbose>
                  <source>1.8</source>
                  <target>1.8</target>
              </configuration>
          </plugin>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>com.zenjava</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>8.8.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>Main.Main</mainClass>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>

<properties>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>
```

And I execute `mvn package` command under the same directory of pom.xml, and it seems the `maven-compiler-plugin 3.5.1` was downloaded fine.

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building PhotoshopUltraLight 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Downloading: 
https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/3.5.1/maven-compiler-plugin-3.5.1.pom
Downloaded: 
https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/3.5.1/maven-compiler-plugin-3.5.1.pom (10 KB at 23.3 KB/sec)
Downloading: 
https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-plugins/28/maven-plugins-28.pom
Downloaded: 
https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-plugins/28/maven-plugins-28.pom (12 KB at 170.3 KB/sec)
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-parent/27/maven-parent-27.pom
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-parent/27/maven-parent-27.pom (40 KB at 446.7 KB/sec)
Downloading: 
https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/apache/17/apache-17.pom
Downloaded: 
https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/apache/17/apache-17.pom (16 KB at 261.3 KB/sec)
Downloading: 
https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/3.5.1/maven-compiler-plugin-3.5.1.jar
Downloaded: 
https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/3.5.1/maven-compiler-plugin-3.5.1.jar (50 KB at 778.5 KB/sec)
```

However, compilation always failed.

```
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR :
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /mnt/c/Users/meifi/Documents/Photoshop-Ultra-Light/src/main/java/Layers/ImageLayer.java:[3,25] error: package javafx.scene.image does not exist
[ERROR] /mnt/c/Users/meifi/Documents/Photoshop-Ultra-Light/src/main/java/Layers/ImageLayer.java:[4,25] error: package javafx.scene.image does not exist
[ERROR] /mnt/c/Users/meifi/Documents/Photoshop-Ultra-Light/src/main/java/Layers/ImageLayer.java:[5,26] error: package javafx.scene.layout does not exist
[ERROR] /mnt/c/Users/meifi/Documents/Photoshop-Ultra-Light/src/main/java/Layers/Layer.java:[4,25] error: package javafx.beans.value does not exist
[ERROR] /mnt/c/Users/meifi/Documents/Photoshop-Ultra-Light/src/main/java/Layers/Layer.java:[5,25] error: package javafx.beans.value does not exist
[ERROR] /mnt/c/Users/meifi/Documents/Photoshop-Ultra-Light/src/main/java/Layers/Layer.java:[6,22] error: package javafx.geometry does not exist
[ERROR] /mnt/c/Users/meifi/Documents/Photoshop-Ultra-Light/src/main/java/Layers/Layer.java:[7,27] error: package javafx.scene.control does not exist
[ERROR] /mnt/c/Users/meifi/Documents/Photoshop-Ultra-Light/src/main/java/Layers/Layer.java:[8,27] error: package javafx.scene.control does not exist
[ERROR] /mnt/c/Users/meifi/Documents/Photoshop-Ultra-Light/src/main/java/Layers/Layer.java:[9,26] error: package javafx.scene.layout does not exist
[ERROR] /mnt/c/Users/meifi/Documents/Photoshop-Ultra-Light/src/main/java/Layers/Layer.java:[10,26] error: package javafx.scene.layout does not exist
[ERROR] /mnt/c/Users/meifi/Documents/Photoshop-Ultra-Light/src/main/java/Layers/Layer.java:[11,25] error: package javafx.scene.paint does not exist
[ERROR] /mnt/c/Users/meifi/Documents/Photoshop-Ultra-Light/src/main/java/Layers/Layer.java:[12,25] error: package javafx.scene.shape does not exist
[ERROR] /mnt/c/Users/meifi/Documents/Photoshop-Ultra-Light/src/main/java/Layers/ImageLayer.java:[11,4] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class ImageView
location: class ImageLayer
```

I have no clue which step was wrong... Any thought would be very appreciated.

Comment: Have you looked at [Getting Started with JavaFX 11](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/)? Event though it's for JavaFX 11, I think you can just change the 11 with 8 and it should help.

Comment: you have to mention the dependency specifically. ImageLayer you are using classes from javafx jar. Add dependency to the pom and compile.

Comment: @Abra: Thanks for pointing me to the resource! I've tried following their pom.xml to set up, but the `<dependency>javafx-controls</dependency>` only starts from version 11, and in our project we were using 8. I tried adding that in pom.xml and same error proceeds.

Comment: @Arundev: Thank you for the suggestion! I thought the `<plugin>javafx-maven-plugin<\plugin>` should care of the dependency? As in their Github page, this is the suggested set up for pom (https://github.com/javafx-maven-plugin/javafx-maven-plugin). If I am misunderstanding anything, please let me know! Thks!

Comment: JavaFX is included with OracleJDK in Java 8.

Comment: @Slaw: I am using openjdk-1.8.0, and I checked its lib, the openjdk version seems not having javafx .jar native. That's why I included the plugin <plugin>javafx-maven-plugin<\plugin>. Shouldn't the plugin download javafx .jar to the project?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11881663/what-is-the-difference-in-maven-between-dependency-and-plugin-tags-in-pom-xml - please read this link

Comment: @Arundev: Thank you for the information! It becomes clearer to me now. I was thinking the `javafx-maven-plugin` plugin would automatically download its own compatible javafx .jar, and distribute it to `lib` folder as well as taking care of the dependency in the project (e.g. by prepend `lib.jfx.` like prefix to the lines that was just `javafx`). Maybe I expected too much from it!

Comment: I also got the reply from `javafx-maven-plugin` project that `openjdk-1.8.0` does not come with javafx. So it seems what this plugin does is to solve the dependency issue of javafx, providing that your jdk has javafx.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle JDK 8 is bundled with JavaFX but not the OpenJDK 8

JavaFX is also removed from Oracle JDK/JRE 11. I was getting the same error with JDK 11. Solved it by including this in pom.xml:

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
    <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
    <version>15.0.1</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Ref:

1. https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#maven
2. https://www.infoworld.com/article/3305073/removed-from-jdk-11-javafx-11-arrives-as-a-standalone-module.html