# Difference between plugins and dependency in maven tool (unpack jar)

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

I'm new to the maven tool, below is what I have understood about plugins and dependency:
**Plugin is a Jar file which executes the task, and dependency is a Jar which provides the class files to execute the task.**
[What is the difference in maven between dependency and plugin tags in pom xml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11881663/what-is-the-difference-in-maven-between-dependency-and-plugin-tags-in-pom-xml)

When I define something in the dependency tag, nothing is downloaded to my target folder. Whereas the same thing defined in the plugin tag downloads it in the target folder. **Why plugin unpacks the jar file?**

Update:
Plugins were unpacked as it was defined in the goal of the plugin.
[image]

Comment: Could you [edit] your question to show your `pom.xml` file?

Comment: Are you running on plain command line or within an IDE? Furthermore can you show the error/warnings you have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Plugins and dependencies are completely different things.

Plugins are used by Maven during the build. They form the different parts of the build.

Dependencies are artifacts that should be used by the Java program you create in your build.

So you e.g. need the Maven compiler plugin to compile the code, but add guava as a dependency if your application wants to use guava.

Answer (score 0):

> When i define something in dependency tag, nothing is downloaded to my
>   target folder.

Exactly, all dependencies are placed into `$USER_HOME/.m2/repository`. They can be used by other mvn projects.

> Whereas same thing defined in plugin tag downloads it in target folder. Why > plugin unpacks the jar file?

Can you share your pom.xml? It may depend on your configuration.